# Return nonexistent right table values as NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE things (
  id INT
);

CREATE TABLE properties (
  thing_id INT,
  name VARCHAR(100),
  value VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO things (id) VALUES (1);

INSERT INTO properties (thing_id, name, value) VALUES
  (1, 'name', 'John'),
  (1, 'age', '123');
```

I want to be able to select properties for a `thing` based on their names, and return `NULL` if such a property doesn't exist. Here is what I have attempted:

```sql
SELECT
  p1.value AS name,
  p2.value AS age,
  p3.value AS foo
FROM
  things AS t
  LEFT JOIN properties AS p1 ON t.id = p1.thing_id
  LEFT JOIN properties AS p2 ON t.id = p2.thing_id
  LEFT JOIN properties AS p3 ON t.id = p3.thing_id
WHERE
  t.id = 1
  AND p1.name = 'name'
  AND p2.name = 'age'
  AND p3.name = 'foo';
```

I wanted the result to be

```
  name |   age | foo
---------------------
'John' | '123' | NULL
```

But unfortunately this query returns an empty result set, because I think such a `p3` doesn't exist.

How can I write a query to do what I want? (And preferably without using explicit `LEFT JOIN`s but commas and `WHERE` conditions instead, because this is a programmatically generated SQL query.) Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can get idea from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `WHERE` conditions on `p1`,  `p2` and `p3` into their respective `JOIN` conditions, otherwise it turns those `LEFT JOIN`s into `INNER JOIN`s (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html)).

```
SELECT
  p1.value AS name,
  p2.value AS age,
  p3.value AS foo
FROM
  things AS t
  LEFT JOIN properties AS p1 ON t.id = p1.thing_id AND p1.name = 'name'
  LEFT JOIN properties AS p2 ON t.id = p2.thing_id AND p2.name = 'age'
  LEFT JOIN properties AS p3 ON t.id = p3.thing_id AND p3.name = 'foo'
WHERE
  t.id = 1
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer as it's the most direct answer to my question. The other answers are helpful as well!

Answer (score 3):

> And preferably without using explicit LEFT JOINs but commas and WHERE conditions instead

It is considered bad style to use old comma-separated joins. Comma-separated joins were used before explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc.) were invented in 1992. One reason for inventing these was that there was no standard syntax for outer joins before. Another was that comma-separated joins are prone to errors and very often less readable. They only exist for compatibility reasons now.

My opinion: Don't even consider using them.

> select properties for a thing

You are dealing with a key/value table here. They are a nuisance to work with. Is there a reason for your data model not just to have tables with explicit columns? A data model containing a table `things` and another `properties` is about the worst I can think of.

The typical approach to get values from a key/value table is conditional aggregagtion:

```
select
  any_value(case when p.name = 'name' then p.value end) as name,
  any_value(case when p.name = 'age' then p.value end) as age,
  any_value(case when p.name = 'foo' then p.value end) as foo
from things as t
join properties p on p.thing_id = t.id
where t.id = 1;
```

If this query is too slow because of too many properties in the table, add a `WHERE` clause:

```
where p.name in ('name', 'age', 'foo')
```

and provide an appropriate index:

```
create unique index idx on properties (thing_id, name);
```

in case you don't already have it.

If your MySQL version is old and doesn't support `ANY_VALUE` then you should consider upgrading. If you don't want to do this or cannot do this, then simply replace `ANY_VALUE` by `MIN` or `MAX`.)

Comment: I couldn't agree more with your comments in this; unfortunately EAV - while it has its place - has become very prevalent as an easy way out of proper database design.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately, this schema is a pre-existing design decision that I have to base my solutions on. How does `ANY_VALUE`/`MIN`/`MAX` in this case compare with a left join, in terms of performance?

Comment: I think it shouldn't make much off a difference. Choose whichever approach you like better. In both cases you should have the mentioned index. The two columns probably form the table's primary key anyway, so it's rather likely this index already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN p.name = 'name' THEN p.value END) AS name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.name = 'age' THEN p.value END) AS age,
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.name = 'foo' THEN p.value END) AS foo
FROM things t LEFT JOIN
     properties p
     ON t.id = p1.thing_id
WHERE t.id = 1
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Note that this returns one row per `t.id` -- even if there are multiple values matching.  If you can have multiple values, then use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

For one `id` the performance should be fine -- particularly if you have an index on `properties(thing_id)`.

One nice thing about performance is that if you add additional columns, then the performance does not change very much -- the effort is more in the aggregation than in counting columns.

With the `LEFT JOIN` approach, the each new column is a new `JOIN`, which can affect performance.  There is often a threshold where one approach is better than the other.  By the way, Nick has the right answer for that approach, which is the more direct answer to your question.